# What's the status of a lease in which the lessor doesn't explicitly assign their interest, but also claims they're no longer the lessor?

Tags: landlord, residential-lease, ohio

I've rented my home for a few years now. The property owner let it be known that she was trying to sell and cash out, which is fine. About a week ago I got a text from her saying the sale went through, she doesn't own the property anymore, and I should be hearing from the new owner, and good luck. Okay.

Well, rent is due in four days and I can't figure out who to pay it to. I still haven't heard from the new landlord. I don't know who they are or where to find them.

I read local and state statutes on this and there doesn't seem to be an explicit landlord's duty to let me know they exist or how to find them.

My take on this situation is that I have a lease with the old landlord, I don't have any direct knowledge of there being a new landlord, and that I should be seeing something like an Assignment of Interest or similar document by now. So come January 1, to the best of my knowledge, I still owe rent to the original lessor.

Is that a correct interpretation?

EDIT per OP Comment:

It's (in) Cuyahoga County, Ohio. The original lessor claims they don't know who the new owner is. Also, tell me I'm wrong here, but I have a contract with Entity A and nothing that assigns that interest to Entity B so don't I still have a contract with Entity A?

Comment: To clarify: In general, what's the status of a lease in which the lessor doesn't explicitly assign their interest, but also claims they're no longer the lessor?

Comment: What city/county is the house? That can make a difference in tenet and lease law.

Comment: Why is the original lessor not providing you with owner's contact information?

Comment: It's Cuyahoga County, Ohio. The original lessor claims _they don't know_ who the new owner is. Also, tell me I'm wrong here, but I have a contract with Entity A and nothing that assigns that interest to Entity B so don't I still have a contract with Entity A?

Comment: This should not IMO be closed as asking for specific legal advice. It is asking what the law requires in a specific unusual situation.

Comment: You might check the county assessor website to see if there's any information on the new owner yet. It may not include their mailing address (that's often redacted). You might also ask the previous owner what title company or lawyer she used and contact them.